# Does the workrate of an employee effect anything during the development stages?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

During the development stages for your game, you go through multiple stages programming and developing various elements of your game, for example Artificial Intelligence, Graphics, Sound, etc.

I have been sending my employees on "time trial" coding exercises, which increase the speed that employee works at, but this does not appear to help me in reaching 100% completion during the development stages for complex projects. In this screenshot below, the slide for the employee assigned to sound is at 100% but only 80% of the work will be completed:

[image]

I am aware that moving the other sliders will adjust this percentage, but I haven't moved the sliders for the last 4-5 games even though this employee's workrate has increased considerable during this time.

Does the workrate of an employee effect anything during the development stages?

Comment: Because of the ammount of question about this topic on the site, I would suggest you to eddit the wiki. It'll help people know what you are talking about!

Comment: @XavierSamuelHuppé I doubt that will stop the person who keeps downvoting all of my questions, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Seemingly not** - for testing I did the following;

Got to development stage 3 for my new game, which presents a screen as below to assign programmers to World Design, Graphics, and Sound:

[image]

As you can see above, I have assigned employees to each area and the only one outstanding currently is Graphics - James E. Garmack. Garmack has the lowest work speed of all three of my employees, so I then moved everybody around a bit without changing any other settings on the screen:

[image]

As you can see, the amount of work that will be completed doesn't change. For reference, these are the stats of my employees:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Speed affects how fast workers produce Tech/Design bubbles.