# What are the effects of overworking or overloading an employee?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

During development of larger and more complex games, you get to assign your programmers based on their strengths. The amount of time they spend on their assigned parts of the game is shown as an accumulative number as you can see on the right of this screenshot:

[image]

Having this number above 100% doesn't seem to have any damaging effects, from what I have seen. What are the effects of overworking or overloading an employee?

Comment: My guess would be it just drains their 'stamina' faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the workrate of an employee effect anything during the development stages?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115568/does-the-workrate-of-an-employee-effect-anything-during-the-development-stages)

Comment: Disagree with the dupe, the questions seem different enough to me.

Comment: @dbemerlin sadly, I think you looked at the similar screenshot and ignored all of the text in the question when you decided to vote to close as a duplicate. I wish more people on this site would open their eyes before clicking on stuff.

Comment: "What are the effects?" vs "What are the effects during the development stage?", they both cover the same mechanic.

Comment: Wrong - "What are the effects of overworking" vs "Does employee speed effect how much work is completed" are two distinctly different questions covering two completely separate mechanics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) If you over-work them you don't get a bonus XP modifier. That xp affects your technology so if you have a lot of research points and want to progress as fast as possible, you need the XP bonus.

2) It drains a lot of extra stamina. For example: Employee just came back from vacation, should last a long time before the next vacation, if you force 200% out of him / her, the stamina would start depleting almost right then and there. You also lose the bonus XP (before publishing the game)

If I find anything else, I'll edit.